# Find cell, paste and format a time value

Tags: excel, time, offset, vba

I want to enter a 3 or 4 digit value into a text box, validate that it is a number, split the number into a 1 or 2 digit minute number and 2 digit seconds number.  I then want to locate a named range on a spreadsheet, move to the right end of that range and then paste  the time value offset a number of cells down from that cell. I also want to format  the cell where I am pasting as a minutes and seconds cell. Most of this works but I am having a problem with the offset paste and format at the very end of the little procedure. 
Now the problem is, pasting the TextBox2 value into that cell.

```
Dim tbV As String
Dim sV As String
Dim mV As String
Dim TimeCell As Range
Dim LastColl As Range

tbV = TextBox2.Text

    If Len(tbV) > 4 Or Len(tbV) < 2 Or Not IsNumeric(tbV) Then
        MsgBox "wrong"
    Exit Sub
    End If


sV = Right(tbV, 2)
mV = Left(tbV, Len(tbV) - 2)


Dim iOffset As Integer
    Select Case Range("AC1").Value
        Case Is = 30: iOffset = 16
        Case Is = 33: iOffset = 20
        Case Is = 22: iOffset = 14
    End Select

Set LastColl = Range("Battery" & BatteryNumber).End(xlToRight)

Set TimeCell = Range(LastCol.Offset(iOffset, 0))

TimeCell.NumberFormat = "m:ss"
TimeCell.Value = TimeSerial(0, Val(mV), Val(sV))
```

Comment: Try `Set LastColl = Range("Battery" & BatteryNumber).End(xlToRight).Offset(iOffset, 0))`? I presume you set `BatteryNumber` correctly somewhere and that range name is valid...

Comment: *Now the problem is, pasting the TextBox2 value into that cell* - What exactly **is** the problem? What happens when you execute `TimeCell.Value = TimeSerial(0,Val(mV), Val(sV))`?

Comment: The problem was that the time variable was being placed on the spreadsheet as an array in the column. The trick was to get the entry range correct and this has been done with the above bit of code. Thank you very much for the repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
Set LastColl = Range("Battery" & BatteryNumber).End(xlToRight)
```

with this:

```
Dim Rng As Range
 Set Rng = Range("Battery" & BatteryNumber)
 Set LastColl = Rng(Rng.Columns.Count)
```